# Get Button Id on the controller using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

**The Objective:**

I have a post with an Ajax.BeginForm and my objective is to get The Button Id on the controller. I've seen examples using  Html.BeginForm, But I need an Ajax form,

**The Code:** C# MVC3

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Valoration", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "HvmDetailTabStrip", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessSaveValoration" }))
{ 
    <div id ="HvmDetailTabStrip">
        @(Html.Partial("_ValorationDetail"))
    </div>
    <button type="submit" style="display:none" id="db1"></button>       
    <button type="submit" style="display:none" id="db2"></button>       
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ValorationModel model)
{
    if ("db1")    
    {
        var result = ValorationService.Save(ValorationModel);
    }
    else
    {
        // ....
    }         

    return PartialView("_ValorationDetail", ValorationModel);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would even work as having 2 `submit` buttons is invalid code and would likely be ignored by the browser.

Comment: What if the user hit's enter/return, which button did he then click?

Comment: But if you there is no inputs, which allows the user to submit the form by pressing enter/return key, you could alter a hidden input value with some javascript when they click the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your buttons' values like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Valoration", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "HvmDetailTabStrip", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessSaveValoration" }))
    { 
        <div id ="HvmDetailTabStrip">
                @(Html.Partial("_ValorationDetail"))
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="db1"></button>       
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="db2"></button>       
    }
```

And in your controller you can write:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(ValorationModel model)
    {
       string buttonValue = Request["submitButton"];

       if(buttonValue == "db1"){
        var result = ValorationService.Save(ValorationModel);
       }else
       {
          ....
       }         

        return PartialView("_ValorationDetail", ValorationModel);
    }
```

Or if count of parameters you pass in method doesn't matter, you can use this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(ValorationModel model, string submitButton)
        {
           if(submitButton == "db1"){
            var result = ValorationService.Save(ValorationModel);
           }else
           {
              ....
           }         

            return PartialView("_ValorationDetail", ValorationModel);
        }
```

Other way how you can solve your problem is here [ASP.Net MVC - Submit buttons with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970504/asp-net-mvc-submit-buttons-with-same-value)